# pip and django-admin work in command prompt but not in git bash terminal

Tags: django, bash, git, git-bash

I have a windows 10, and when I try `pip --version` or `django-admin --version` in cmd, it works and I get the version number. When I try using `pip` or `django-admin` in my git bash terminal I get the error bash: pip: command not found.

So I'm thinking the error isn't without my path variables because `pip` and `django-admin` work in cmd. How else can I make it work in my git bash terminal?

Comment: How do you start your "git bash terminal"? Is that some specific terminal that comes with git on Windows? Because both git and bash are independent of each other, and indepedent of any terminal.

Comment: git bash is the app I use start my bash terminal

Comment: Then it will be your PATH variables inside that app; they appear to be independent of your settings for `cmd`. So you'll have to set those separately. Whether git-bash follows Windows path conventions here, or *nix conventions, I don't know.

Comment: Is this the Git Bash you're using: https://gitforwindows.org/ ?

Comment: yup, that's the one

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be your path variables because git-bash doesn't necessarily know about the cmd's path.

As an alternative, if you are using Windows 10, give Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL2) a try.  Using Ubuntu18, and VSCode, it works great, getting full *NIX experience.

Comment: So check my path variables if the django is installed there?

Comment: is Windows Subsystem another way to use bash?